# Is there way to have ordered output without ORDER BY clause in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-server-2014

We have a large application. Recently, we upgraded the database MS SQL 2016. As a result, we are having issues with output order in some reports. Unfortunately, we can not alter the source code of the application and will not be able to do this for awhile. The reason for this behavior is that some queries in format "SELECT * FROM table" with is no "ORDER BY" clause on them.

Is there any creative way to order the output? Like to add a trigger on SELECT<(I know there is no such thing...)>? Any other way? Any type of index that would be an ORDER default?

UPDATE: I can not alter the source code. This is compiled application and upgrade cycle is few months away. If I could, I would just go through the source code and change those queries.

Comment: I don't suppose you can just turn that other query into a subquery?  `SELECT t.* FROM (unchangeable application query here) as t ORDER BY t.column`

Comment: Use views, with order, and let your reports select those views.

Comment: @MarcGuillot - views are unordered too. Unfortunately, even SSMS gets this wrong and generates code that makes it look like you can order views. It'll sometimes look like it works but it's by no means guaranteed to remain consistent.

Comment: SQL Server has unordered sets.  Without an explicit ORDER BY, there is not GTD of the order

Comment: Well, you should never rely on the "order" of a result set without explixit `order by`. Reminds me of the `select top 100 percent` used in Views to be able to add `order by`, when SQL Server optimized it customers where complaining *our application is broken* :-)

Comment: Where do you have the results stored ?

Comment: If you don't order in the database, you need to order in the application.  Such are the laws of SQL.

Comment: I can not alter the application source code. The source code is compiled and next upgrade cycle is few months away. Unfortunately. If it were possible to have a trigger on select but, there is no such thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> Is there a way to have ordered output without an ORDER BY clause in MS SQL

**No.**

Unfortunately, there is not.

SQL (in all its flavors) is a declarative scheme for manipulating sets of rows of tables. Sets of things like rows have no inherent order.

If SQL, in any flavor, without `ORDER BY` statements, happens to deliver rows in an order you expect, it's a coincidence.  It's pure luck.  Formally speaking, without `ORDER BY` SQL delivers rows in an unpredictable order."Unpredictable" is like "random," but worse. *Random* implies you might get a different order every time you run the query: you can catch that kind of thing in system test. *Unpredictable* means you get the same order each time until you don't.  Now you don't.

This is in the basic nature of SQL. Why? The optimizers in modern database servers are really smart about delivering exactly what you asked for as fast as possible, and they get smarter with every release. SQL Server 2016's optimizer probably noticed some opportunities to use concurrency for your queries, or something like that, and took them.

Your choices here are all unpleasant:

- Roll back the database upgrade. That *may* or *may not* fix the problem.
- Make emergency fixes to your software load and roll them out ahead of schedule.
- Live with the wrongly-ordered reports until you can fix your software.

I wrote a long answer here so you can have useful arguments to present to your corporate overlords about your situation. I don't envy you when you explain this.